# Await Action() is not awaited

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I'm using ZXing.Net.Mobile library to scan QR codes. I would like to put the code responsible for scanning to separate class so I could just call a method from it and it would return the result. Something like that:

```
var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();

var result = await scanner.Scan();

if (result != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + result.Text);
```

It's an example from official repository, but it doesn't work (at least for me).
So I created a class and put the code that DID work form me elsewhere. Here's the class code:

```
public class QrHandler 
{
    public ZXingScannerPage scanPage { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public async Task<string> Scan()
    {
        var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
        {
            PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>
            {
                ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
            },
            TryHarder = false,
            AutoRotate = false,
            TryInverted = false,
        };

        scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
        scanPage.AutoFocus();

        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
                try
                {
                    Result = result.Text;    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Result = ex.Message;
                }
            });
        };

        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
        return Result;
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it from a method like below:

```
public async Task<string> Validate()
{
    string _Result = "OK";
    QrHandler q = new QrHandler();
    _Result = await q.Scan();
    return _Result;
}
```

The problem is that Validate() returns _Result before q.Scan() returns any value. Shouldn't it be fired when after q.Scan() completes?

Comment: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` accepts `Action<T>`, which does not allow any return type to be specified, and as only methods that return `Task` or `Task<T>` can be awaited, your async lambda will run synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return from `Scan()` until the `OnScanResult` event handler has been executed.

It's unclear when this event is being raised but provided that it's atually raised when you'd expect, you may block asynchronously in the `Scan()` method using a `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
public async Task<string> Scan()
{
    var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
    {
        PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>
        {
            ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
        },
        TryHarder = false,
        AutoRotate = false,
        TryInverted = false,
    };

    scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
    scanPage.AutoFocus();

    using (SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1))
    {
        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;

            Device.InvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
                try
                {
                    Result = result.Text;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Result = ex.Message;
                }
                semaphore.Release();
            });
        };

        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I will have to read up on SemaphoreSlim to understand why it worked, though :)

Comment: Small question. I overlooked you had changed BeginInvokeOnMainThread to InvokeOnMainThread and ran it with Begin.. It worked, though. Why did you changed it for Invoke..?

Comment: @robs23: To wait for the delegate to be executed. I realized you can still not exit the method until it has.